# Bad usage mount -t cifs

Tags: mount, cifs, spyder

I want to mount a webfolder (NAS-storage) via the terminal. 
In the end I want to be able to open documents via 'Spyder3' (a python IDE) stored in the webfolder.

The manual of the host gives this command

```
mount –t cifs //nas.ads.mwn.de/<share_name> <mountpoint> -o username=<lrz-kennung>,domain=ADS
```

I adapted it for my paths etc. to

```
sudo mount –t cifs //nas.ads.mwn.de/USER /media/ferdi/webdisk -o username=USER,domain=ADS,vers=2.1
```

this results in:
 mount: bad usage

I checked the package with:

```
 apt list cifs-utils
```

this results in:
Listing... Done
cifs-utils/bionic,now 2:6.8-1 amd64 [installed]

I'm not sure about the `vers` (the meaning and the correct usage). That is just what was written in the host's manual.

Answer (score 0):

The "vers" argument seems to be quite tricky and it highly depends on the Samba version of the server (in this case your NAS box). From the man page:

vers=args means SMB protocol version. Allowed values are:

- 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.0 and 3.1.1 (or 3.11)

From my experience is better for you to try with different versions to find out which one runs with your combination of cifs-utils versions VS. NAS's Samba implementation version.

And to avoid bad results on the tests you make, I recommend you to use the IP instead of the host name ;)

Comment: Didn't help.
Thanks for the explanation anyways.